# Xamarin, Firebase: " Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process" - though initializeApp() is called?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin

Im starting to go crazy over that line:

Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.TalkAboutTv.TalkAboutTv. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

I have no clue what is causing that. I AM calling FirebaseApp.IntApp(this) and my package name is matching ... Why is it not working?

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}



protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

    firebase = new FirebaseClient("2131099704");
    Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);

    FirebaseDatabase.Instance.GetReference("chats").AddValueEventListener(this);

    fab = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.fab);
    edtChat = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.input);
    lstChat = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list_of_messages);


    fab.Click += delegate
    {

        PostMessage();
    };



    if (FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser == null)
        StartActivityForResult(new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(SignIn)), MyResultCode);
    else
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Welcome " + FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Email, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        DisplayChatMessage();
    }
}

private async void PostMessage()
{
    var items = await firebase.Child("chats").PostAsync(new MessageContent(FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Email, edtChat.Text));
    edtChat.Text = "";
}

public void OnCancelled(DatabaseError error)
{

}

public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
{
    DisplayChatMessage();
}

private async void DisplayChatMessage()
{
    lstMessage.Clear();
    var items = await firebase.Child("chats")
        .OnceAsync<MessageContent>();

    foreach (var item in items)
        lstMessage.Add(item.Object);
    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, lstMessage);
    lstChat.Adapter = adapter;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to initialize firebase within your Application class (OnCreate method).
But first download the google-services.json file from the project console, and make sure it has the "GoogleServicesJson" value as Build Action.

Comment: Helo :) Thanks for your tip: I found the problem, i had to edit the csproj file with notepad and edit it so that it would include the json file.

Comment: I have all this and also check in csproj, but I still have problem :(

Answer (score 5):

One thing you *don't* need to do any more is to call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` from your `MainActivity.OnCreate()` method. If you're doing this, you should probably remove that call, as it's unnecessary and may cause downstream complications.

I tried deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders, I made sure that my `google-services.json` had the correct `GoogleServicesJson` build type, and that the build type was being correctly picked up in my `fsproj` (or `csproj` if you're still using C#) file. Yet the error was still happening.

What I had done wrong was that I had a typo in my package name. If you have performed all of the steps above, check the `package_name` field in your `google-services.json` file, and make sure it corresponds exactly with your project's package name. *Then* clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 3):

I was spinning up a new app and I did not have Internet Permissions enabled. This fixed my issue

Comment: This seemed to fix it for me but then it.came.back.

Comment: Try to delete bin and obj folders

Comment: Ummm... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026783/why-does-my-android-project-compile-without-any-standard-references

Answer (score 0):

if none of the above has worked for you. check the project settings. in 'AndroidManifest.xml' add or verify you have the following. inside application
`<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" /> <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /> <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" /> <category android:name="${id app from firebase console }" /> </intent-filter> </receiver>`

Comment: is that project id ("A user-assigned unique identifier for your Firebase project. This identifier may appear in URLs or names for some Firebase resources, but it should generally be treated as a convenience alias to reference your project") or app id("Use this number to identify your app when you contact Firebase support.") or public facing name, or project number or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This error came to me when i changed the contents of the .json file pointing to a new firebase database.

I cleaned the project and build it again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue today, you will need to avoid more than 1 application in your Firebase project, as a turnaround and be sure to choose the "GoogleServiceJson" for the generation of your google-service.json