# Why does my Android project compile without any standard package references?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Not that I'm complaining, but...

I was having trouble compiling my Android project and I went nuclear and deleted all of my "Xamarin.Android.Support" packages. When I next compiled, a dialog popped up in VS and I was asked to install some Android stuff and now it compiles fine.

Except, there are no longer any package references to these official packages.

What just happened...?

Comment: Prior to this, you have recently upgraded the VS version or the XF version. It may be that the old version of the "Xamarin.Android.Support" packages in the previous version is incompatible. When you delete it, VS will help you choose the latest version to install when reinstalling, so there is no problem.

Comment: Ok, but why doesn't the project have references anymore to "Xamarin.Android.Support" packages?

Comment: You mean now not references anymore to "Xamarin.Android.Support" packages.Oh,a strange phenomenon! Do you try to build clean,then rebuild project?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I do clean, rebuild routinely.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Try creating a new Android project with the latest setup and those packages aren't there.

Comment: @lan Warburton Okey , If recreating a new Project ,  NuGet Package need to reinstall.